# Jboss AS 7.1.1 Final Local JNDI EJB Invocation

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi

Using Jboss AS 7.1.1 Final, I'm trying to invoke a Local EJB(3.1) through JNDI.

My Local EJB is:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "Services")
@LocalBean
public class Services implements ServicesLocal {
.....// scary stuffs here
}
```

My Interface Services is:

```
@Local
public interface ServicesLocal {
.... // Some powerfull stuffs here
}
```

I'm trying to invoke this EJB above like this:

```
private ServicesLocal getLocalEJB() throws NamingException {
        log.info("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n ################## Getting the ServicesLocal");
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        return (ServicesLocal) context.lookup("ejb:/global/docs/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.local.ServicesLocal");
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting when invoking this code above:

> ############ Getting the ServicesLocal
>
> 15:36:10,437 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.client] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) JBoss EJB Client version 1.0.5.Final
>   15:36:10,456
>
> ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:global,distinctname:docs] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@396f6a24
>   15:36:10,457 
>   ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ^Iat org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)

And this is the JNDI log when the Jboss 7.1.1 Final boot. Having the EJB that I want to invoke:

> 15:07:07,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-7) JNDI bindings for session bean named Services in deployment unit subdeployment "docs-ejb-0.1.jar" of deployment "docs.ear" are as follows:

```
java:global/docs/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.local.ServicesLocal
java:app/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.local.ServicesLocal
java:module/Services!com.mycompany.docs.local.ServicesLocal
java:global/docs/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.services.Services
java:app/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.services.Services
java:module/Services!com.mycompany.docs.services.Services
```

I think my `context.lookup("ejb:/global/docs/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.local.ServicesLocal")` is wrong. What I can do to fix that and invoke my Local EJB with JNDI?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use what JBoss tells you?

`context.lookup("java:global/docs/docs-ejb-0.1/Services!com.mycompany.docs.local.ServicesLocal")`

Your EJB is stored in `java` namespace, not in `ejb` one.

Comment: Yes, I have tryied to copy and paste that line. Same error message